# Uncomplicated window interface for displaying status in python

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a window in python where I will be displaying the status of a large system, a bunch of numbers or some LEDs. The idea is that the system sends messages to the display thread and the thread updates different parts of the window, like displaying a number or turning the color of a field. More importantly, the user interacts with system via command line of python interpreter, e.g. executing commands or updating variables.

One may simply suggest that I need to use one of the GUI packages, like pyqt or xwpython. But these modules are designed to build GUIs, that means they have plenty of resources to handle events moues clicks and so on, which I don't need. Also, these modules run a event loop which is a waste of resources as well as in many cases they block the python shell.

I tried to use pyqt without running the main loop. But when I do this windows thinks my application is not responding, and I get a bunch of problems. For example the close button on the window does not work, and any effort on closing it crashes my python session.

Any ideas on how I can implement my application?

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear, I need to be able to create windows just like matplotlib does when you plot a figure in the intractive mode. The mainloop of the figure does not block the interpreter. Does any one know how they do it? I know it is very discouraged to start the mainloop in a thread, so they should be doing it some how else.

Comment: If the interactive matplotlib figures are exactly what you want, why not simply use them?

Comment: No, matplotlib does not have exactly what I want. I only to have their frame work. I will need other functionalities which are not available in matplollib.

Comment: Maybe you want to go in more detail about what functionality that is you need. Because, indeed, if you need a fully functional GUI, you will need to create one and then indeed this GUI needs an event loop blocking the console.

Comment: Well, I am trying to use python for experiment control in a physics lab. I am used to doing this in Matlab where you can have a gui in the interactive mode. Now I am trying to do the same in Python, because python is free and handles multi-threading much batter than Matlab. In python, may be the GUI can be run in a new process that is created in python which handles the  GUI? would that be possible?

Comment: You could of course embedd IPython into your GUI. Something like https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider to use the Apache's Superset dashboard.

#### Check this up:

https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html
It makes amazing dashboards incredibly easy and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am looking for something native to python, rather than going through a server and a browser.

Comment: I don't know how simple or how complex you want to go far... But there's always Tkinter to make some windows for you... Look that: [Tkinter LED Panel](http://robotic-controls.com/learn/python-guis/basics-tkinter-gui)

Comment: I tried pretty much all the GUI modules, (tkinter, PyQt, xwPython,...) and nothing close to what I wanted.

Comment: Well... In this case, I suggest you make a simple HTML page, showing a pyplot image or something like that and make a simple Flask app to feed and refresh it... otherwise, I'm out of ideas... hope it help you...